# How can I display detail view by fetching details entered to the database before on clicking an item of list view

Tags: android

I have a List View displaying list of Tasks created. Now, when I click on Task1 it should display the detail view of Task1, by fetching the details entered while creating task1. I am trying to do this with "id" and "position" both obtained when i override the OnItemClick method. Are these two enough and please let me know how to achieve this objective, all suggestions are welcome. Please kindly help me.

My OnItem Click method as of now:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The position of the item clicked is " +position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
              int taskID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("task_name._id")); //Get the merchantID
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The name of task clicked is " +taskID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            }

        });
```

I am using the below method to populate the list view from database:

```
public void populateListView() {

        SQLiteDataBaseAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataBaseAdapter(this);

        Cursor cursor = adapter.getAllData();

        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{SQLiteHelper.UID, SQLiteHelper.CONTACTS};
        int[] toViewIds = new int[]{R.id.textViewNumber, R.id.textViewName};

        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.custom_list_row, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIds, 0);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);



    }
```

My List View appears as shown below:

Task1
Task2
Task3
Task4....

When I click on Task1, I want the details of Task 1 to be displayed. Please help me. thanks in advance. Please help me learn.

Comment: hi, it depends on the structure of your database...you have tables set for the items and for item details?

Comment: No, I do have a table which consists of all fields. Can't I fetch data from there, should I have another please guide me. Sorry for late reply..

Comment: If you can post 1 record item it will help me a lot

Comment: @Johan V: Means, do you want to see the fields present in the detail screen? please do let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I want to have a clear picture of your data so that I may design the database structure

Comment: For example..i have list of people with name, surname, address, id

Comment: Ok Sure. I have a table with the following fields as columns:
name:
description:
remarks:
date_time:
actual_completion_time:
estimated_time:
notify_time:

Comment: If you need more information. Please let me know.

Comment: Im writing an answer..but need coffee first sry..please wait :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see if we need a database or not depends on how much complex will your app's data get.

If this is the only data it will host still you have to decide if the data needs to be persist on in the device even if no internet is available.

If the data gets complex (more tables etc) or data must persist you have to create a local database.

For simplicity lets assume this is the only data.

What you can do to do a master detail app flow make your app structure as follows :

[image]

You need to create a custom java object class mapping the properties of your data. Create a new Java file name it Task and see the below code :

```
public class Task {

private String name;
private String description;
private String remarks;
private String date_time;
private String actual_completion_time;
private String estimated_time;
private String notify_time;

public Task() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getRemarks() {
    return remarks;
}

public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
    this.remarks = remarks;
}

public String getDate_time() {
    return date_time;
}

public void setDate_time(String date_time) {
    this.date_time = date_time;
}

public String getActual_completion_time() {
    return actual_completion_time;
}

public void setActual_completion_time(String actual_completion_time) {
    this.actual_completion_time = actual_completion_time;
}

public String getEstimated_time() {
    return estimated_time;
}

public void setEstimated_time(String estimated_time) {
    this.estimated_time = estimated_time;
}

public String getNotify_time() {
    return notify_time;
}

public void setNotify_time(String notify_time) {
    this.notify_time = notify_time;
}
}
```

Now in your Main Activity declare a public static Array of Task Objects like so :

```
public static ArrayList<Task> mTaskList = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the on create method of the Main Activity fill the array with data.

Then in the list fragment on cerateView get a reference to the Main Activity mTaskList and pass it to the adapter.

When clicking in the listView you can then get the item position and attach it to an intent and retrieve it from the detail fragment. The detail fragment will also get an instance of the mTaskList in the main activity.

This is a solution without creating the database.

Please tell me how I can help you further.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I was creating a java class named "Task". thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since I am doing something similar Ill take a swing at this.  It would have been helpful to know what your database looks like, as well as where you want to send the data.  But here are some chunks out of a database fetch program that I have.  Mine generates a list of items, and then when clicked on it pulls that items info from the database.

```
OnCreateView(...)
  myDatabase = new DatabaseConnector(rootView.getContext());
  myDatabase.open();
  String search_key ="item";   // The name of the record im getting
```

Ill put this function below, but it takes a string, and an enum to determine what table to look up in,  if you only have one you wont need that.

```
  Cursor query = myDatabase.getOneItem(search_key,Table.Spell);
```

Now at this point you can use it (query) as a cursor, or as I did, turned it into a ContentValues type.  Im sure there was a good reason I did this... but at this point I don't remember what it was.

```
  if (query != null)
  {
       database_values = myDatabase.theCursorHandler.toContentValues(query);
  }
  else  
  { 
       database_values = null;  
  }
  myDatabase.close();
```

I think the reason I did it was that I would have a ContentValues type that contains all of the data tagged with the column names from the database.
example:  Name   Birthday   Gender column names would get me a ContentValues that looks like  Name : Bill   Birthday : March 5th  Gender : Male  and will not need changed even if I change the structure of the database.

Now you just have to get what you want out of the database_values

```
if ((database_values != null) && (database_values.containsKey("description"))
{
     String description_string = getdatabase_values.getAsString("description");

     // Do whatever it is you want with the string you have from the database.
}
```

Everything above here should be able to be copy pasted as a unit and run, mine was a bit more of a mess because I had formatting, and fragments as well as savedInstanceState things in it, so I hope I haven't deleted anything that was important.  The real workhorse of what is above, is my DatabaseConnector class which is at the bottom here (again I trimmed out all the excess and hopefully didn't trim too much).

DatabaseConnector()

```
public class DatabaseConnector extends SQLiteAssetHelper 
{
    private static final String DatabaseName = "simpledatabase";  // Database Name
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;  // Im not srue why the database version is 2, ive not set it as far as I can tell!
    private SQLiteDatabase database;    // The database


    public DatabaseConnector(Context context)
    {       
   // Works
       super(context, (DatabaseName), null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Opens the database.  Will need to see if it creates one if not found
    public void open() throws SQLException
    {
         database = getReadableDatabase();
    }

   public Cursor getOneItem(String name, Table table)
   {
        // Works!  Insensitive comparison of data items.
        return database.query(table.name(),null,"Upper(name)= Upper(\"" + name + "\")",null,null,null,null);
   }

   ContentValues toContentValues (Cursor data)
   {
       ContentValues value = null;
   // Check that data is something.
   if (data != null)
       {
           value = new ContentValues();
           if (data.isAfterLast())
           {
               // data was after the last entry, throw a null until I figure out how to throw an exception.
               return null;
           }
           // Be sure Cursor is pointing to at least the first row.
           // if it is pointing to some other row then we move it to the first.
           if (data.isBeforeFirst())
           {
                data.moveToFirst();
           }

           String[] column_names = data.getColumnNames();
           String temp_value ="";
           for (int i = 0; i < column_names.length;i++)
           {
               // Get the value out of column[i]
               temp_value = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(column_names[i]));
               // Set the value into the Content at name with value
               value.put(column_names[i], temp_value);
        }
    return value;               
       }
       else
       {  // Data was null, so output null.
          return null;
       }
}
```

Hope this helps, and hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. Can I please which android version are you aiming at? I am aiming Lollipop...

Comment: Sorry for late reply.

Comment: Low end was api 8. ,You will want to look up the sqlassethelper class.  It helps a lot and someone else wrote that

Comment: I did not understand that. Its working for me now. Followed the solution presented above.